# How to create a Notification cancel dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, notifications

I have a notification which tells the user that its downloading a file with its progress..
I want to make a dialog with some textviews displaying some info and 2 buttons which are Close and Stop (stops the download).
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the AlertDialog Class

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     alertbox.setMessage("Downloading");

    alertbox.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        // do something when the button is clicked
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
           ..... //cancel code
        }
    });

    alertbox.setNegativeButton("Pause", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        // do something when the button is clicked
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            .... //pause code
        }
    });

    // display box
    alertbox.show();
```

Comment: Same question: How do I connect the notification with this class? Can I update the whats in the dialog each time the notification gets updated?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a custom dialog where your text views are defined in xml and you can use your xml to set as view in your custom dialog box.

you can code like this:-

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    LayoutInflater factory = null;
        factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        dialogView = factory.inflate(R.layout.yourXml, null);

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(yourActivity.this)
            .setTitle(R.string.rate_title)
            .setView(dialogView)
            .setPositiveButton("Stop", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

              // Add your stop code here
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                // dismiss dialog here

                }
            })
            .create();
```

Comment: How do I connect the notification with this class? Can I update the whats in the dialog each time the notification gets updated?